# TextView Gravity Not Working in TableLayout

Tags: android, xamarin.android

My table is populated by dynamic data, so I am adding TableRows and its Views in the code. The TableLayout and the first row (my header) are built in the xml.  Gravity set to center works on these items.  But setting the Gravity to center on my dynamically created TableRows and Views is not working.

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/poweredEquip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dip">        
    <TableRow
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected"
      android:gravity="center">
      <TextView
        android:text="Serial"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="130px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Model"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="110px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_column="2"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Status"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_column="3"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Tool Turned"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_column="4"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Hours"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="110px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_column="5"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Trailer Model"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="110px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_column="6"/>
    </TableRow>
<TableLayout>
```

Activity.cs

```
TableLayout powered = (TableLayout) FindViewById(Resource.Id.poweredEquip);
TableRow.LayoutParams p = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent) {Gravity = GravityFlags.Center};
TableRow.LayoutParams p1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent) {Column = 1, Gravity = GravityFlags.Center};

TableRow row = new TableRow(this) { LayoutParameters = p };
text = new TextView(this) {Text = dr["Serial"].ToString(), LayoutParameters = p1};
text.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
text.SetMaxWidth(150);
text.SetMinWidth(150);
row.AddView(text);

powered.AddView(row);
```

Comment: Yes.  Everything works except the alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Can you post your XML layout for the textview's (just 1 or 2) that work?
2. Stab in the dark, but you might want to try setting the LAYOUT_GRAVITY for the text's layout parameters instead of the GRAVITY since you are forcing the width to be 150. Specifying the Layout Gravity as CENTER should force the entire TEXTVIEW to move to the middle of the parent container (Table Row).
3. Another thought: When you set the layout params for the TextView, it's using TableRow.LayoutParams. I *think* it might actually be setting the parameters in reference to the table row, not setting the parameters of the TextView itself. Try calling this on each TextView you create before adding it to the table row:

   `text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`

Comment: Added some TextViews to original code.  I am not seeing Layout_Gravity as a member of TableRow.LayoutParams.  What would that be under?

Comment: It seems like there isn't a proper way of setting layout_gravity on a textview in the code behind. Can you set the textview's (in the code behind) to have some background and set table rows to have a different coloured background, let it run and take a screenshot? That will give us some idea where how the labels are being set (gravity, size) within the table rows.

Comment: I set the TextView background to orange and it looks like the TextView is taking up the entire width of the column regardless of the length of the text.  The text is just always aligned to the left.

Comment: In that case see my edited post above. The text may not actually be getting centered within the textview.

Comment: Setting Gravity on the TextView fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: This fixed my issue. Setting gravity to center did not work when trying to set it on the TableLayout or the TableRow. It's interesting that this worked. I guess we can consider the TextView inside the row to be a "cell". That helps my thought process anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want same property for your tablerows then you can do it easily.

Just use get layout param from your xml layout and then set those layoutparmas to your dynamic table row.

xml_table_row = (TableRow) findviewbyid (R.id.xml_table_row_id)
TableLayout.layoutparam param = xml_table_row.getLayoutParams();

powered.AddView(row, param);

Hope it will help you. If not please response so that i can try someother way.